# Start new Activity from spinner

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, crash, spinner

I am trying to start a new activity when I select an option from my spinner but whenever I select the option that starts a new activity the app crashes. I am starting the new activity with an intent and I am using onItemSelected for the spinner

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Abs extends Activity {

private Spinner StretchType;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.abs);
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTypeofStretch);

}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    StretchType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSType);
    StretchType
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
 // **************************** below here is where I start the new activity
        switch (pos) {
        case (1):
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Practice.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
        // **************************** above here is where I start the new activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Show your logcat it will be easy to solve your problems..

Comment: When you say crash, please post logcat trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to outer class using `classname.this`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Abs.this, Practice.class);
Abs.this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: THANKYOU very much, you wouldnt happen to know how to create a alert dialogue with a custom layout that has a spinner in it that does what I asked above would you?

Comment: @user2109242 I see you are trying to use an Activity as a dialog, nothing bad. But You may want to do a custom alert dialog as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) , in place of a button as shown in tutorial, you can place a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `startActivity(i)` with the following -

```
 Abs.this.startActivity(i);
```

Also, I see that you are extending `Activity` for the `SpinnerAdapter` class. Is that needed at all?